# Permutation matrix and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof: For every invertible matrix $A$ there is a permutation matrix $P$ and an invertible upper triangular matrix $R$ and $R'$, such that $A=R'PR$...

Can someone give me a hint? I dont even know where to start

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: Are you sure you want A=R'PR Can you show me the excercise?

Comment: @Jam i am....i would show you but its in german....but i nearly translate word by word so should be correct

Comment: @Dmitry i know lu decomp....but does that apply`?

Comment: you want a factorization A= upper triangular * permutation *upper triangular?  its wierd that the pemutation matrix is in the middle.

Comment: Well, I can't be sure since I'm not sure I parse your statement correctly. Are both $R$ and $R'$ upper-triangular?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758968/if-a-in-m-n-n-mathbb-f-is-invertible-then-a-upb-u-is-unipotent-upp?rq=1

Comment: @Dmitry i think they are both upper triangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you matrix  has as $a_{11}$ entry zero permute the row with a non zero row. Now start doing gauss ellimination. Keep all the accounting in matrix forms. Remember multiplying a matrix from the left gives sou row combinations as gauss ellimination does. Multiplying from right gives you collumn combinations. Can you do a similar method to get your result? (A is invertible so its not a zero matrix and a diagonal matrix is also an upper traingular) .