# Describing the double cosets $LgU$ for $g\in\operatorname{GL}_n$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, matrix-decomposition, permutation-matrices

This is with reference to Artin's *Algebra*'s Exercise M.11 of Chapter 2. I have managed to show that any invertible matrix can be decomposed as $lpu$ where $p$ is a permutation matrix, and $l$ and $u$ are lower and upper triangular matrices with $U$'s diagonal entries being $1$. What Artin asks next is to describe the double cosets
$$LgU := \{lgu : g\in\operatorname{GL}_n\text{ and }l, u \text{ meaning the obvious matrices}\}.$$

In a previous exercise, I have proven that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then their double cosets partition the group. So it is easily seen that each $LgU = LpU$ for some permutation matrix $p$.

**Question:** Is there anything more to this description? For instance, can two distinct permutation matrices be in a same double coset?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the Bruhat decomposition (which is $LPL$) but close.

Since $g=lpu$ where $l\in L, u\in U, p\in P$, you have $LgU=LpU$. Suppose that $p,q$ are permutational matrices and $l_1pu_1=l_2qu_2$, so $LpU=LqU$. Then $lp=qu$ for some $l\in L, u\in U$. Then $lpe_i=que_i$ for every standard basic vector $e_i$: $le_j=q(u_i)$, where we denote by $x_i$ the $i$-th column of matrix $x$, $j=p(i)$.

Let $i$ be such that $p(i)=n$, so $le_n=q(u_i)$. So $l_{n,n}e_n=q(u_i)$. Since $q(u_i)$ has coordinate $1$, we see that this coordinate of $q(u_i)$ must be number $n$, other coordinates are $0$, all coordinates of $u(i)$ except coordinate number $i$ are $0$ and so $q(i)=n$.

Now let $p(i_1)=n-1$. Then $le_{n-1}=l_{n-1}=q(u_{i_1})$.
Then $q(i_1)=$ either $n$ or $n-1$. The first option is impossible, so $p$ and $q$ coincide on $i,i_1$ (equivalently, $p^{-1}, q^{-1}$ coincide on $n,n-1$).

Continue this way, consider $n-2,...,1$ and prove that $p^{-1}=q^{-1}$. So $p=q$. Thus $LpU=LqU$ iff $p=q$.

A proof can also be found on [this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=LMRTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=LpU%3DLqU,%20Lower%20and%20Upper%20triangular&source=bl&ots=8SEsZj6Cr0&sig=ACfU3U24nKVSiHeku8PNcsNfsRJ5AMDgew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLnO6BzMf1AhVxJUQIHSAfBB4Q6AF6BQiJARAD#v=onepage&q=LpU%3DLqU%2C%20Lower%20and%20Upper%20triangular&f=false) of the book "Combinatorial matrix theory" (by Richard A. Brualdi, Ángeles Carmona, P. van den Driessche, Stephen Kirkland, Dragan Stevanović), theorem 1.1.10.

Comment: I am failing to decompose $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ as you claim, before even attempting a proof. Can you please show?

Comment: Fixed ${}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: This was brilliant! (And complicated, my brain hurt.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

It seems to me that the following things are better for solving this problem.
Let
$$
{t_{ij}(\alpha)={\begin{bmatrix}1&&&&&&\\&\ddots &&&&&\\&&1&&\alpha&&\\&&&\ddots &&&\\&&&&1&&\\&&&&&\ddots &\\&&&&&&1\end{bmatrix}}}
$$

So $t_{ij}(\alpha)a$ is the matrix produced from $a$ by adding $\alpha$ times row $j$ to row $i$; and $at_{ij}(\alpha)$ is the matrix produced from $a$ by adding $\alpha$ times column $i$ to column $j$.

Multiplying on the left by a matrix of this form with $i>j$, and multiplying on the right by a matrix with $i<j$.

Comment: Yes, I used that in showing the $lpu$ decomposition. But I don't see how this can be used in describing the cosets $LpU$'s.

Comment: Could you please specify the edition of Artin's book. In my edition (1991) the exercise you discuss is M12. And there is no sequel.By the way, I think you can find the answer to your question here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758968/if-a-in-m-n-n-mathbb-f-is-invertible-then-a-upb-u-is-unipotent-upp?rq=1).

Comment: I am using the second edition. (I will have a look at the linked question soon.)

Comment: I wish I had the second edition of this book.

Comment: I can share that with you over GDrive, @kabenyuk. Email address?

Comment: The answer you linked doesn’t answer my question. It shows what I had already that I had proven.

Comment: Can you delete that, since it doesn’t answer the question?

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems to me that Ewan Delanoy's answer [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758968) is the answer to your question.  The answer is actually this.There is exactly one permutation matrix $p$ in every double coset of the form $LpU$. This is exactly the result in the answer of markvs.

Comment: Doesn’t it only show that $LAU$ contains a permutation matrix for any invertible A?

Comment: I see that in both cases it is proved that it follows from the equality $LpU=LqU$ that the permutation matrices $p=q$.